# I want to write a simple script to insert date and time in any file in Windows

Tags: windows, scripting, timestamp

I work in a secure data environment so my ability to install software is pretty limited. I have Notepad++, but don't have TextFx (and I read it doesn't work in the current version anyway). I don't have the Python plugin for Notepad++ either. No AHK, etc. OS is Windows XP.

I'm trying to find another way to write a basic script that I can use to insert a time and date stamp into any text editor. I did some googling but couldn't find any specific examples.

I noticed that Notepad uses F5 for date/time stamp, so I tried to find the file/code it uses for that, but no luck.

Any tips? Looking for something like a batch file I can assign a KB shortcut to use across text editors, Word, or whatever. Thanks!

Comment: `for %f in (*.txt) do date /t >> %f`

Comment: Marc, is this something I could program to work globally by putting it in a file and then assign a KB shortcut to it. Or would it just work in Notepad++? Still not familiar with this kind of scripting and how to make it all work. I usually program within a single program like R, SAS, Stata, and don't have any general programming experience in Python, etc.

Comment: it's to be used in a .bat file or directly at a command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it sounds like you are looking for would be a key macro. The functionality you are describing is implemented within the program itself, and is not available for global usage throughout the OS.

As you are on Windows XP I am not sure what options are available without a software installation. There is no built in macro recorder for Windows XP unfortunately.

If you are in Word, then you could use the built in Office macros to accomplish this. How exactly depends on your version of Office.

Comment: Thanks Ian! I manage to make things work in Word, Excel, etc., but still wish I could setup something global. It's so great to use Phrase Express on my personal computer.